# c++ Class pointers - compilation error

Tags: c++

I have no idea why I cannot compile this peace of code:

header:

```
class AnimationDisposer {
  public:
    void onStart(void);
    void onStop(void);
    void onPause(void);
    void onResume(void);
    void onRewind(void);
    void ongoing(void);

    typedef void (AnimationDisposer::*animationCallback)(void);
    static animationCallback mAnimationCallbacks[ANIMATION_STATE_SIZE];
};
```

and then in .cpp:

```
void (AnimationDisposer::*mAnimationCallbacks[ANIMATION_STATE_SIZE])(void) = {
&AnimationDisposer::onStart,
&AnimationDisposer::onStop,
&AnimationDisposer::onPause,
&AnimationDisposer::onResume,
&AnimationDisposer::onRewind,
&AnimationDisposer::ongoing,
};
```

The errors are (six same, just different functions):
src\AnimationDisposer.o:AnimationDisposer.cpp:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `Animations::AnimationDisposer::onStart()'

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are those functions implemented?

Comment: It compiles OK for me in VC++ 2013.

Comment: Your error isn't a compilation error; it's a linker error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's linker error - these functions were in a file, which was not attached to the project...

Thanks for help, I am blind...